# Restrict CPU frequency from going too high

Tags: 8.1-oreo, cpu, oneplus-6

I got a OnePlus 6 running on Snapdragon 845. The CPU can clock up to 2.8GHz, which is very battery-consuming. I want to limit the CPU clock frequency to, say for example, 2.2GHz or another value I desire. It's better if the frequency limit can be applied automatically at boot.

Phone is rooted with Magisk 16.6 and TWRP is installed. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Apps like Kernel Adiuotor, Spectrum and 3C toolbox I know of and others can do as well I suppose

Comment: If comfortable with Tasker you could set up those CPU profiles and configure them to activate at boot